# how to create action url for hyperlink in liferay?

Tags: liferay

i have a requirement that when i click on hyperlink  i will send one parameter course id it has to go to action method in portlet class.then i need to display the success and as well as failure message on after operation done on to browser!

```
 public void DeleteCourses(ActionRequest request,ActionResponse response) throws IOException,PortletException
    {

        String cid=request.getParameter("courseId");

        long courseId = Long.parseLong(cid);
        try {
            CourseLocalServiceUtil.deleteCourse(courseId);
            } 
         catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

can any one tell me how to create action url for hyperlink?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write it on your JSP like the following:

```
<portlet:actionURL name="DeleteCourses" var="DeleteCoursesURL">
     <portlet:param name="courseId" value="the_course_id"></portlet:param>
</portlet:actionURL>

<a href="${DeleteCoursesURL}"> Delete Course </a>
```

And Since your portlet class inherits from `MVCPortlet` the name of the your method `DeleteCourses` should be the same as the name of the `actionURL`

You could check a full example [here](http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.0/development/-/ai/developing-a-portlet-with-multiple-actions)

And for the Success and Error message you could simply use liferay built-in feature for this like that:

```
 <liferay-ui:success key="success" message="Course deleted successfully!" />
```

And for the errors:

```
 <liferay-ui:error key="error" message="Course could not be deleted" />
```

You could check an example [here](http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.0/development/-/ai/passing-information-from-the-action-phase-to-the-render-phase)